# Detect any device like Computer, Mobile, Tablet using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website with login and registration system. I want that a user who has signed up already with an email or contact no, next time he/she will not able to signup with any other email or contact no using the same device. I have tried with detecting the IP address of the user, however, it is not that what I want. Is there have any way to detect the user's device-specific information?

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

I want to store device-specific information, the device can be anything an android device, iPhone, a windows pc or mac or iPad anything

Comment: what does the header user-agent gives you?

Comment: "Is there have any way to detect the user's device-specific information?" The best you can do is browser fingerprinting, but that's not terribly reliable and is trivial to bypass. You're better off just setting a cookie.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: The quick answer is no, as any method you try and use can be easily bypassed simply by clearing the cache, and IP address won't work as they're often shared.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it with PHP. 1 IP can be assigned for thousands of people. People can also have dynamic IP. Look for JS browser fingerprinting lib but even that can't give you confidence that you will not cut off someone new.

https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 send identifier to PHP (ajax or cookie) and save in the database.